# What is the difference between sentiment analysis (e.g. on Facebook) and Twitter sentiment analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sentiment-analysis

I'm bit confused with the names of sentiment-analysis and twitter-sentiment-analysis.I want to do sentiment analysis for facebook fan page posts.so I decide to use an api but I did not found any api which gives sentiment analysis for facebook Posts.Every api service is made twitter.I found datumbox api which gives results for sentiment-analysis and twitter-sentiment analysis [here](http://www.datumbox.com/machine-learning-api/).

for facebook sentiment analysis, do I need to go with sentiment-analysis api or twitter sentiment-analysis.(I know Name itself suggests sentiment is for twitter tweets).

Is their any api that provides sentiment analysis for facebook posts data ?

or

facebook trained datasets with the classes of POS,Neg,Neu?

Comment: anything what you can get "sentiment" in considered sentiment analysis. What I try to say is that: you can do sentiment analysis on absolutely anything what does have text or emoji i'm counting also :) you just need to collect data and start exploring (my opinion). Airlines companies does do a sentiment analysis on survey are collected on their site. I currently do a project what involve twitter, facebook, linkedin and google+  so even if it is graph API you can extract what you need for analysis.

Comment: @sb0709  you are saying that Sentiment analysis is something that contains text or emojis.using that we make a sentiment. Right? If that is right twitter also contains text or emojis !! what makes difference is just #hash tags and @mentions? you said that you are working on linkedin and google+ .Are you trying to get any public data(PAGES) by accessing apis.if yes ! plz share some stuff.I tried to get the public pages data from google+ and linked-in but I did not find any source to start.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specifically called `Twitter sentiment analysis`, rather its colloquial. `Sentiment analysis` is a common term and could be applied on any dataset depending upon the use-case considered.

I have not came across any facebook api for scraping posts (maybe there are privacy concerns, as sometimes you cannot see fb pages when you are not an user), nevertheless there are several apis to scrap tweets from twitter, even specifying person, geographic location, language.

[here](https://gist.github.com/sivu1/537cefa03a83ee4a1beb7cd581a71f40) is a github gist for reference, it uses python tweepy module to grab current tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter sentiment analysis as the name suggests is ideal for Twitter data. They are different because for sentiment analysis of Twitter data, we can handpick some features for example, `emoticons` can be tagged earlier with their sentiment and also `hashtags` can be understood. Whereas a generic sentiment analysis mostly doesn't include these. Also, for twitter dataset the data is hardly a `sentence` of two that is 160 characters for which the model might be different from others.

I don't know of any API specific for facebook data, but if your dataset is small you can give Twitter API a shot else if generic sentiment analysis might do a good option.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any api for facebook post either.

I'm doing a project to keep an eye on our competitor's facebook information update. My manager asked for report of analysis of one of our competitors.I think that's sentiment analysis.

So I started to look for some [website scraping tool](http://www.octoparse.com/) to collect post from their posts.

Some people said that facebook has strict anti-bot measure. So I was just trying.

But that bot worked.

Here's the result I got. ( I bulk collected what people are saying in their facebook group. )

If you don't find any api that provides sentiment analysis for facebook posts data, I think that will be a great solution. Scraping post is a little tricky.
To locate the right place of the data you need to write XPath in the bot.

[image]

Comment: If you find that API thing, pls share.

Comment: you can get facebook page data(posts) using graph api.You can't get personal or person data using graph api.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api is the api @M John

Comment: @M John  sentiment-analysis is something that is done on the english sentences to determine the polarity of that sentences(positive,negative,neutral).facebook posts mostly look like english sentences and the content is longer when compare with twitter.In twitter we can only write 160 chars of message.Hope you get the what I'm saying

Comment: @DilipBobby, you can get comments also from graph api: Comment /{comment-id}

A comment can be made on various types of content on Facebook. Most Graph API nodes have a /comments edge that lists all the comments on that object. The /{comment-id} node returns a single comment.